# piecewise vector field and composition of piecewise functions

Tags: plotting, vector, piecewise

I have the following vector field

```
u[x_, y_] := Piecewise[
   {{{0, -1}, x < y <= -x },
    {{1, 0}, y < x <= -y },
    {{0, 1}, -x < y <= x},
    {{-1, 0}, -y < x <= y }}]
```

$u(x,y) = \begin{cases} (0,-1) & x < y \leq -x\\
    (1,0) & y < x \leq -y\\
    (0,1) & -x < y \leq x\\
    (-1,0) & -y < x \leq y
    \end{cases}$

defined on $x\in [-1,1]$ and $y\in [-1,1]$ which looked like this

[image]

I am interested in plotting the self composition

$
    f(x,y,t) =u(x- t u_1(x,y),y- t u_2(x,y))
    $

for $t\in \mathbb{R}$.  Unfortunately, my attempts to define this function and plot it are met with errors regarding the depth of objects.  Help in defining the composition of piecewise functions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please post the formula in Mathematica code instead of LaTeX code so we need not type it again.thanks.

Comment: Sorry, here it is: `u[x_, y_] := Piecewise[
  {{{0, -1}, x < y <= -x },
   {{1, 0}, y < x <= -y },
   {{0, 1}, -x < y <= x},
   {{-1, 0}, -y < x <= y }}]`

Comment: What are $u_1$ and $u_2$ (and where is the code for $f$)?

Comment: u_1 and u_2 are the components of the vector field u defined above, i.e. u = (u_1, u_2).  For $f$ I tried ```f1t[t_?NumericQ] := u[x + t u[x, y][[1]], y][[1]]
f2t[t_?NumericQ] := u[x + t u[x, y][[2]], y][[2]]``' but this failed